# Pentaho - Erro ao tentar escrever numa tabela Oracle

Tags: pentaho

Criei um processo no PDI que faz uma consulta numa tabela Postgres (step Table Input) e depois seleciona os campos desejados (step Select value) para depois executar a inserção dos metadados desses campos numa tabela Oracle (spep Table Output).

erro:

ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Errors detected[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPkaG.png)